# Cloning from GitHub on Jenkins: could not load PEM client certificate

Tags: git, jenkins, github, certificate, clone

I set up a build server and want to clone a project in Jenkins.

I get the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/habitat-sh/sample-node-app/': could not load PEM client certificate, LibreSSL error error:02FFF00D:system library:func(4095):Permission denied, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)

It is on public GitHub, no certificates should be needed, everything is working correctly when I clone on terminal. Also, curl works without any problems.

Do you have any ideas what causes the issue? Have tried a lot of stack overflow solutions, e.g. setting `git config --global http.sslVerify` to `false`, but none of them is working

(the OS is macOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue myself. The problem was, that the Jenkins-user was not able to access the ssl certificates, that I set in the GitConfig

```
git config --global http.sslCert "~/Documents/certificates/cert.crt"
git config --global http.sslKey "~/Documents/certificates/cert.key"
git config --global http.sslCaInfo "~/Documents/certificates/cert-ca.crt"
```

Surprisingly, there was no permission error shown, which made this issue hard to debug.

What helped was moving the certificates in the directory of the Jenkins user.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I fixed only after I did the following:

brew uninstall git
[image]

next, I went back to repo directory and did `git fetch` in terminal and Keychain access opened the popup asking for my password in credentials title. I put my password and clicked on "Always allow" button. After that, all forked or cloned repos have been updated successfully with `git pull`.

I hope this helps others.

my configurations:

- big Sur version 11.4
- git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

considerations:
*I have added the GitLab self-signed valid certificate in my Keychain System months ago*