# Having trouble pulling from github using TeamCity 10.0 with an uploaded Key

Tags: git, github, ssh, timeout, teamcity

This is an older version of TeamCity that we have to keep running for historic purposes. I'm having some trouble with it though: Github is deprecated basic username/password auth, so I want to switch this to using uploaded keys. I uploaded my ssh key, and I switched the fetch URL to use ssh:

```
git@github.com:OrgName/RepoName.git
```

And then I switched the auth method to Uploaded Key, removed the Username, and selected the key. I've double checked the key, it definitely works. However, I can't even seem to connect to github to even get that far. Clicking Test Connection spins for a bit, then times out:

```
Test connection failed in RepoName :: Release Build - Windows/NET
List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

What could be the problem here? Something with the older version of TeamCity that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/ssh-keys-management.html), make sure to select:

- the private key (not the one ending with `.pub`)
- a key in [PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091503/bitbucket-git-clone-results-in-fatal-unable-to-access-could-not-load-pem-c/62106861#62106861) (`ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -P "" -f myKey`) (or [convert your existing key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66237922/6309)), instead of ppk or the [old OpenSSH one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309).